# Как поменять название пакета androidstudio?

Tags: android-studio

Здраствуйте! Нечайно назвал приложение не правильно, т.е. оно начинается с com.exemple.MyApp. Подскажите как поменять com.exemple. на нужное мне название не переписывая весь проект?

Comment: Через Refactoring можно.

Comment: А как это через рефакторинг?

Comment: Это в контекстном меню будет, которое через ПКМ вызывается над пакетом.